# Windows7 Command prompt closed immediately after Open?

Tags: windows, windows-7, cmd, windows-7-x64

I am using a Windows 7 Machine. Whenever I open the command prompt it will open for a few seconds and then close immediately.

Can someone please let me know what can be the issue?

Comment: Have you read [7 Ways to Launch the Command Prompt](http://www.7tutorials.com/7-ways-launch-command-prompt-windows-7-windows-8)? All fails?. Under `Win+R`, try `cmd.exe /D /K` or `%ComSpec% /d /k` or `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /D /K` or even `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /D /K`

Comment: Yes i have read that but those fails also tried mentioned by you also same issue i am getting

Comment: Try 32-bit version `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /d /k` after clearing Windows prefetch cache. Run as administrator?

Comment: I got same issue from following command but how to clear Windows prefetch cache?

Comment: Google is your friend:). And what about `%ComSpec% /d /k pause`

Comment: For %ComSpec% /d /k pause its saying Press any key to Continue... but close within few second

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73169/discussion-between-josefz-and-subodh).